# Error (LibrarianErrorDomain error 2) when turning iCloud sync off for a UIDocument file with setUbiquitous

Tags: ios, ios5, icloud

I am running into an error when I try to turn iCloud sync off for a UIDocument file. Wondering if anyone else has run into this. Here's the scenario:

I create a UIDocument file locally in the app sandbox and then make the following call to begin syncing the file with iCloud:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:localPathURL destinationURL:cloudPathURL error:&error];
```

Everything's going swimmingly.

Now I want to stop iCloud syncing for this file.

I first make sure that the file has at least been synced with iCloud by calling the following:

```
- (BOOL) isDataFileSyncedWithCloud
{
    if (![self isICloudSupported] || ![self isUsingICloudForFiles])
        return NO;

    NSURL* file = [self getFileURLToCloudDatafile];
    NSNumber*  isInCloudNum = nil;

    if ([file getResourceValue:&isInCloudNum forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey error:nil])
    {
        // If the item is in iCloud, see if it is downloaded and uploaded.
        if ([isInCloudNum boolValue])
        {
            NSNumber*  isDownloadedNum = nil;
            if ([file getResourceValue:&isDownloadedNum forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey error:nil])
            {
                NSNumber* isUploadedNum = nil;
                if ([file getResourceValue:&isUploadedNum forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey error:nil])
                {                    
                    return ([isDownloadedNum boolValue] && [isUploadedNum boolValue]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The above returns YES, indicating the file has been synced (or so I thought...)

So, now I go ahead and make the call below to stop iCloud syncing for this file:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:localPathURL destinationURL:cloudPathURL error:&error];
```

and I get the following error: "The operation couldn't be completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 2 - Cannot disable syncing on a unsynced item.)"

Any idea why this error is occurring and how I can get rid of it? I would have thought that my file was fully synced...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. To disable iCloud syncing, I was accidentally calling:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:localPathURL destinationURL:cloudPathURL error:&error];
```

instead of

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:cloudPathURL destinationURL:localPathURL error:&error];
```